# coroutine receiving data with a thread calculating throughtput in python

Tags: python, multithreading, yield

I want to have a coroutine accepting data continuously and making it yield the speed at fixed intervals (for example: in terms of items received per minute)

```
@coroutine
def speed(target=None):
    messages = Queue()
    def calculate():
        while True:
           time.sleep(1)
           messages.put(1/count)
    Thread(target=calculate).start()
    while True:
        item = (yield)
        count += 1
        ... how do I receive messages in a nonblocking fashion?
```

I'm trying to figure out wheather I need to launch a thread and use a queue to yield from that queue, or some other way to do this parallel calculations (speed, throughput, avg, emit last value at fixed intervarls, etc)

Comment: Is this real Python code?

Comment: Yes, not a complete program, but real code. The `coroutine` decorator is from @dabeaz

Comment: Well I assume you're missing a `def` on the second line, and on the 9th line it the `t` should probably be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using a thread.

```
@coroutine
def speed(interval, target):
    # calculate events per second on every received item
    def counter():
        print "thread started"
        while True:
            time.sleep(interval);
            # send to redis, message queue, local storage, coroutine or whatever you need
            # ...
            print "inside thread. count = %s per %s seconds" % (speed.count, interval)

            if close:
                target.close()
                print "end of thread"
                return

            with lock:
                speed.count=0

    lock = Lock()
    speed.count=0
    close=False

    t=Thread(target=counter)
    t.daemon=True
    t.start()

    try:
        while True:
            line = (yield)           # Receive a line
            with lock :
                speed.count+=1

    except GeneratorExit:
        #signal the counting thread to close
        close = True
```